# Wordpress attach stylesheet to custom template page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I just want to attach a style sheet to my custom template page. I don't want to add it to my header.php file. I want it inside my template file. How do I do this ?

I have added my custom template code below. I want to attach a external style sheet and I want to use it inside my custom template file.

Thanks in advance :)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: User Registration
*/
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Registration Form</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/registration-style.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>    <![endif]-->
   </head>

 <body>
 <div class="container">
 <section class="register">
  <h1>Register on iMomen</h1>
  <form method="post" action="index.html">
  <div class="reg_section personal_info">
  <h3>Your Personal Information</h3>
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Your Desired Username">
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your E-mail Address">
  </div>
  <div class="reg_section password">
  <h3>Your Password</h3>
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Your Password">
  <input type="password" name="confirm" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  </div>
  <div class="reg_section password">
  <h3>Your Address</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="">Egypt</option>
    <option value="">Palastine</option>
    <option value="">Syria</option>
    <option value="">Italy</option>
  </select>
  <textarea name="textarea" id="">Your Full Address</textarea>
  </div>
  <p class="terms">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
       I accept  <a href="http://www.imomen.com/">iMomen</a>Terms & Condition
    </label>
  </p>
  <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign Up"></p>
  </form>
  </section>
 </div>

<section class="about">
Download it for free from <a href="http://www.imomen.com/">iMomen</a>
</section>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Whats your template file like `single`, `page` or `archive` template?

Comment: This is an extremely poor method of templating a page. You're circumventing the entire WP core. Why even bother using Wordpress at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your not using the wordpress header file!
whats stopping you just adding the link in your make shift code above?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="link-to-style.css">
```

if you use the theme header file, you could add the css on a page to page basis!

```
<?php if(is_page('custom-page')){?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="link-to-style.css">
<?php } ?>
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

in your template/page you can try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/yourfolder/block.css' ?>">
```